# Losing opacity transition after image click

Tags: html, css

I'm using a css opacity transition for a mouse hover but whenever you click on the image then click outside the image (to bring the images back jquery) the css transition doesn't work anymore.

my css transition

```
 .grid li a:hover img {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opactiy .2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
     }

 .grid:hover li {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opactiy .2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 0.3;
    }
```

Instead of posting a whack load of code I thought jsfiddle would be better.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/29/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the inline styles are overriding the CSS styles. You can remove the style attribute once you're done with the animation and that will make sure it doesn't override the CSS styles. http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/Djby5/1/

```
$('#hidden').click(function() {
    $grid_li = $('.grid li');
    $grid_li.find('img').animate({ width: '339px', height: '211px' });
    $grid_li.siblings().fadeIn();
    $grid_li.siblings().animate({opacity: 1, top:'0px'}, 1000, function(){
       $(this).removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```